# Can Heapsort be applied on Min Heap Data Structure?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap

I've read and been told that Heapsort can only be applied on Max heap, but this article [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort-for-decreasing-order-using-min-heap/) states otherwise.

So, is it true that HeapSort can be applied also on Min heap?

Comment: Where did you read that? It's wrong, a max heap is conceptually **identical** to a min heap, you just flip all comparison operators, or equivalently you can also negate all values.

Comment: So heapsort can be applied to Min Heap also?

Comment: Yes. There's no reason why it can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with a remark.

Heapsort works by first creating a heap (which can be min or max), then repeatedly extracting the root of the heap, putting it in the destination array, and restoring the reduced heap.

Usually, this is performed in-place, so that the destination array coincides with the source array, and the roots are copied where there is room. The heap doesn't move, it shrinks by dropping the last leaf every time.

With the usual indexing scheme, we have the following partitioning of the array:

```
Root | Heap | Sorted
```

With a Max heap, at the end of the sort the elements will be stored in increasing order, and with a Min heap, in decreasing order.

If you want the reverse order, you can either flip the whole array after sorting, or change the indexing scheme to achieve the partition

```
Sorted | Heap | Root
```

It is unsure which of the two approaches is fastest.